# How to use mmap'd reserved kernel memory in get_user_pages_fast()?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, mmap, dma, reserved

I have reserved several GB of memory via `memmap=nn[KMG]$ss[KMG]` in the kernel cmd line parameters. I also have a custom char device driver which uses `mmap()` and `write()` from the `file_operations` struct and performs DMA operations to a custom PCIe device. I use the typical [DMA API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) to create the scatter-gather list.

In my driver, `mmap()` is successful and I can read/write to this `io_remap_pfn_range()` memory all day long from user-space. My driver's `write()` function is supposed to use the mmap'd buffer to create a scatter-gather list.

However, my driver's `write()` function fails with `EFAULT` when calling `get_user_pages_fast()` and I cannot explain why. If I use a malloc'd buffer instead of an mmap'd buffer from user-space everything works as expected.  **It seems to be a problem with the way `get_user_pages_fast()` handles the mmap'd buffer. What's the workaround?**

For example,

```c
/* From user-space
 * What currently works but has poor performance
 */

int fd;
FILE *fdat;
char *buf;
ssize_t rc;
size_t len = 4*1024*1024*1024; /* 4GB */

fd = open("/dev/mycooldev", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
rc = posix_memalign(&buf, 4096, len);
fdat = fopen("mydat.bin", "r");
fread(buf, 1, len, fdat);
fclose(fdat);
rc = write(fd, buf, len);
close(fd);
```

```c
/* From user-space
 * What I want to do, i.e. use the many GB of contiguous reserved memory
 */

int fd;
FILE *fdat;
char *buf;
ssize_t rc;
size_t len = 4*1024*1024*1024; /* 4GB */

fd = open("/dev/mycooldev", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
buf = mmap(0, len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
fdat = fopen("mydat.bin", "r");
fread(buf, 1, len, fdat);
fclose(fdat);
rc = write(fd, buf, len);
close(fd);
```

Relevant `write()` function in my device driver:

```c
/* From the char device driver
 * buf is a pointer to the buffer returned from either 
 * posix_memalign() or mmap(), but mmap() doesn't work
 * because of get_user_pages_fast()
 */

ssize_t mycooldev_write(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *pos)
{
    int rc;
    struct page **pages;
    size_t npages;
    struct sg_table sgt;
    unsigned long uaddr, start, end;

    ...

    /* EDIT: I added this call per a request in comments */
    if (access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, buf, len) == 0) {
        pr_err("Not allowed to access user address\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    uaddr = (unsigned long)buf;
    start = uaddr & PAGE_MASK_64; /* (0xFFFFFFFF00000000 | PAGE_MASK) */
    end = uaddr + len + PAGE_SIZE - 1;
    npages = (end - start) >> PAGE_SHIFT;

    pages = kcalloc(npages, sizeof(struct page *), GFP_KERNEL);

    /* This call fails with EFAULT when user passes in a buffer
     * obtained with a call to mmap(). If user calls posix_memalign()
     * to obtain their buffer, get_user_pages_fast() is successful.
     */
    rc = get_user_pages_fast(uaddr, npages, 1, pages);

    rc = sg_alloc_table_from_pages(&sgt, pages, npages, pos, len, GFP_KERNEL);

    ...
}
```

Why does `get_user_pages_fast()` not like my mmap'd buffer, but is fine with the malloc'd one? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only place I can see that returns `-EFAULT` in `get_user_pages_fast` is when the call to `access_ok` returns 0. To verify whether that is in fact the case, could you add a call to `access_ok` in your `mycooldev_write` and see if it returns 0 there too?

Comment: Ok, I tried it and edited my `mycooldev_write` to show what I did.  `access_ok` did not return 0, meaning the call was successful. Arghh what does that mean?

Comment: That's a shame. The call to `access_ok` in `get_user_pages_fast` will actually see your `uaddr` as the address and your `npages << PAGE_SHIFT` as the length, but I don't think that will make much difference (`access_ok` only does a basic range check on the address and length). I'm not sure where your `PAGE_MASK_64` comes from. I guess it has the same value as `PAGE_MASK`?

Comment: Actually, there are a few places in "mm/gup.c" that could return `-EFAULT`, but they mostly seem related to problems faulting in the pages. That shouldn't be a problem for reserved memory as it shouldn't need faulting in.

Comment: Edited to add a comment about `PAGE_MASK_64`... I mean, it's probably not necessary for me to do it like this, but it's left over from some previous troubleshooting and it didn't seem to hurt, so I left it in...

Comment: I'm starting to think the pages do have to be faulted in. Can you explain your reasoning thinking they don't?  I'm beginning to look into the `(*nopage)` or `(*fault)` function pointers in `vm_operations_struct`.

Comment: They may have to be faulted in to process virtual address space (possibly via the `(*nopage)` or `(*fault)` VM operations you mentioned), but I'm thinking that if you are mmaping to reserved, physical memory, it should never be swapped out, so should never need paging in.

Comment: IMHO but the mmap() function gets swappable pages, the file attached to it is precisely to swap the pages to a proper place.  Most probably the get_pages_fast will fail because your pages are not physically allocated.